# Can i take $-1$ instead of $1$ in $xy +t=1$ ? Atiyah book

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have some confusion in Atiyah Commutative algebra

Here is an  outline

> Let $A$ be a ring and $\mathcal{m}$ a maximal ideal of $A$, such that every element of $1+\mathcal{m}$ is a unit in $A$. Then $A$ is a local ring.

> Proof :Let $x\in A\setminus\mathcal{m}$. Since $m$ is maximal, the ideal generated by $x$ and $\mathcal{m}$ is $(1)$.
> Hence there exist $y \in A$ and $t \in m$ such that $xy +t=1$

**My thinking** : Here $(1)= A$ and $x\in A\setminus\mathcal{m}$. The ideal generated by $x$ and $\mathcal{m}$ is strictly larger  than $\mathcal{m}$

$$ \implies (x)+ \mathcal{m}= (1)=A$$.

there exist $y \in A$ and $ t \in$ m such that $xy +t=-1$ since $-1 \in A$

**My question**  : Can  i take $-1$ instead  of $1$ in  $xy +t=1$  ? I mean  $xy +t=-1$

Comment: Definitely you can take

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The important point is that any unit will generate the entire ring, and knowing that $(x)+\mathfrak{m} = (1)=A$ implies that there exist some $y\in A$ and $t\in\mathfrak{m}$ such that $xy+t = u$ for some unit $u$, in which case $xy=u-t$. But recall that the condition you are given is that every element of $1+\mathfrak{m}$ is a unit, so really you are more interested in the fact that $$xyu^{-1}=uu^{-1}-tu^{-1}=1-t$$
so that $xyu^{-1}$ is a unit (since $1-t\in 1+\mathfrak{m}$), in which case $x$ is a unit. But since $x\in A-\mathfrak{m}$ was arbitrary, it follows from part i) of the same proposition (1.6) that $\mathfrak{m}$ is maximal, and that $A$ is a local ring.

(That $x$ is a unit follows from the fact that $xyu^{-1}$ has some inverse $z\in A$, and hence $yu^{-1}z$ is inverse to $x$.)